# Default configuration in python/django

Tags: python, django, python-import, verbosity

I'm working on a reusable django app, which I want to make configurable by GLOBAL VARIABLES in settings.py.

I want these to be optional so I've provided default values inside my app in a conf.py module, where I have the following:

```
GLOBAL_1 = "Def value for global 1"
GLOBAL_2 = "Def value for global 2"
GLOBAL_3 = "Def value for global 3"

try:
    from settings import GLOBAL_1
except:
    pass

try:
    from settings import GLOBAL_2
except:
    pass

...
```

So defaults can get overwritten by configuration in settings.py should they exist. 
This method won't scale for too many variables so I was wondering if there's a less verbose way to do this. Maybe I should use eval()?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `eval`. If you have to ask, you don't.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GLOBAL_1 = getattr(settings, 'GLOBAL_1', 'Def value for global 1')
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i did, but had to import settings first, like this settings = __import__('settings') Thanks a lot.

Comment: importing settings: from django.conf import settings